# Vuze client on Rhel 5 machine

Tags: bittorrent, vuze

I downloaded the vuze client for linux(Rhel 5) and xtracted the tar file.When I execute the vuze launcher I get the following error. Am trying to debug the issue , in the mean time any linux experts have any idea on this issue ? Someone tried to install vuze on linux and encountered this issue.

```
[root@localhost vuze]# ./vuze
Starting Azureus...
Suitable java version found [java = 1.6.0_24]
Configuring environment...
Java exec found in PATH. Verifying...
Browser check failed with: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
Auto-scanning for GRE/XULRunner.  You can skip this by appending the GRE path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and setting MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME.
  checking /etc/gre.d/gre.conf for GRE_PATH
GRE found at /usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9.
Browser check failed with: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
Can't create browser.  Will try to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and hope Vuze has better luck.
setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to: /usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9
setting MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME to: /usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9
Loading Azureus:
java -Xmx128m -cp "./Azureus2.jar:./swt.jar" -Djava.library.path="/root/Desktop/Downloads/vuze" -Dazureus.install.path="/root/Desktop/Downloads/vuze" -Dazureus.script="./vuze" -Dazureus.script.version=2 org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main 
file:/root/Desktop/Downloads/vuze/Azureus2.jar ; file:/root/Desktop/Downloads/vuze/swt.jar ; file:/root/Desktop/Downloads/vuze/
changeLocale: *Default Language* != English (United States). Searching without country..
changeLocale: Searching for language English in *any* country..
changeLocale: no message properties for Locale 'English (United States)' (en_US), using 'English (default)'
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.<init>(Main.java:114)
        at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.Main.main(Main.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.aelitis.azureus.launcher.MainExecutor$1.run(MainExecutor.java:37)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
        at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.mainwindow.SWTThread.<init>(SWTThread.java:84)
        at org.gudy.azureus2.ui.swt.mainwindow.SWTThread.createInstance(SWTThread.java:63)
        at com.aelitis.azureus.ui.swt.Initializer.<init>(Initializer.java:163)
        ... 12 more
Exit from Azureus complete
No shutdown tasks to do
Azureus TERMINATED.
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the swt.jar file inside the downloadable Vuze is for 64 bits systems. Just go to http://www.eclipse.org/swt/ and download the stable release from there.

Open the tar.gz and extract swt.jar and overwrite the one from vuze.